# Group rows partially [Python] [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.x, groupby

Good morning everyone.

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd

info = {
'states': [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
'values': [34, 29, 28, 30, 35, 33, 33, 36, 40, 41] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=info)

print(df)

>>> 
    states   values
0       -1       34
1       -1       29
2       -1       28
3        1       30
4        1       35
5       -1       33
6        0       33
7        1       36
8        1       40
9        1       41
```

I need to group the data **using PANDAS** (and/or higher order functions) (*already did the exercise using for loops*), I need to group the data having the "states" column as a guide. But the grouping should not be of all the data, I only need to group the data that is neighboring... as follows:

Initial DataFrame:

```
    states   values
0       -1       34 ┐
1       -1       29 │    Group this part (states = -1)
2       -1       28 ┘
3        1       30 ┐    Group this part (states =  1)
4        1       35 ┘
5       -1       33     'Group' this part (states = -1)
6        0       33     'Group' this part (states =  0)
7        1       36 ┐
8        1       40 │    Group this part (states =  1)
9        1       41 ┘
```

It would result in a DataFrame, with a grouping by segments (from the "states" column) and in another column the sum of the data (from the "values" column).

Expected DataFrame:

```
    states   values
0       -1       91     (values=34+29+28)
1        1       65     (values=30+35)
2       -1       33
3        0       33
4        1       117    (values=36+40+41)
```

You who are more versed in these issues, perhaps you can help me perform this operation.

***Thank you so much!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making use of `shift` to create different groups based on consecutive values of the `states` column, after which you can use `groupby` to add the values in the `values` column:

```
(
    df
    .assign(
        # create groups by checking if value is different from previous value
        group = lambda x: (x["states"] != x["states"].shift()).cumsum()
    )
    # group by the states and group columns
    .groupby(["states", "group"])
    # sum the values in the values column
    .agg({"values": "sum"})
    .reset_index()
    # select the columns needed in the final output
    .loc[:, ["group", "values"]]
)
```

Comment: Oxbowerce thank you very much, Your answer is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> It's not the problem about grouping the elements, it is the problem related to consecutive elements. The approach should be of using consecutive iterations.

> Here I've saved all the results in a list. Don't use any dictionary to store results as its key values should be unique.

[image]

> Your desired output ☝️

Comment: It would help if you could post the code you used as a code block instead of image, as it makes it easier for others to copy and try out.

Comment: Pragyan Tiwari, Thank you very much for your time and your answer...